# spring security 3.x to 4.x migration issue

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, migration, spring-3, spring-4

I am trying  to **migrate spring security 3.x to 4.x**,

while doing so I had the following error

```
Aug 27, 2016 11:16:03 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadRootSmartSoapEndpointInterceptor#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'wsSecurityInterceptor' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'wsSecurityInterceptor' defined in class path resource [META-INF/webservice/config/spring-ws.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'springSecurityHandler' while setting bean property 'validationCallbackHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityHandler' defined in class path resource [META-INF/webservice/config/spring-ws.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'authenticationManager' while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationManager' defined in class path resource [META-INF/webservice/config/spring-ws.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5068)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5584)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1572)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1562)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadRootSmartSoapEndpointInterceptor#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'wsSecurityInterceptor' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'wsSecurityInterceptor' defined in class path resource [META-INF/webservice/config/spring-ws.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'springSecurityHandler' while setting bean property 'validationCallbackHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityHandler' defined in class path resource [META-INF/webservice/config/spring-ws.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'authenticationManager' while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationManager' defined in class path resource [META-INF/webservice/config/spring-ws.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:467)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1071)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'wsSecurityInterceptor' defined in class path resource [META-INF/webservice/config/spring-ws.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'springSecurityHandler' while setting bean property 'validationCallbackHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityHandler' defined in class path resource [META-INF/webservice/config/spring-ws.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'authenticationManager' while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationManager' defined in class path resource [META-INF/webservice/config/spring-ws.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:320)
    ... 44 more
```

The error is pointing towards following dependency

```
   <bean id= "authenticationManager" class= "org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
      <property name="providers">

            <bean class= "org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
                <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userManagerWs"/>
            </bean>

        </property>
    </bean>
```

**What changes are required to make it work?**

Thank you in advance :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The empty constructor on class [ProviderManager](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.1.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/ProviderManager.html) was already deprecated at least from Spring Security 3.1.2:

> Constructor Summary
>
> ProviderManager()
>
> **Deprecated**. *Use constructor which takes provider list*
>
> ProviderManager(List providers)
>   ProviderManager(List providers,
>   AuthenticationManager parent)

In spring-security 4 this [constructor](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/ProviderManager.html) has been removed, so that's the root of problem:

> Could not instantiate bean class
>   [org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager]: No
>   default constructor found; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.()

You should configure this way in order to work:

```
<beans:bean id= "authenticationManager" class= "org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:list>
                <beans:bean class= "org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
                    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userManagerWs"/>
                </beans:bean>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
    </beans:bean>
```

Or, using spring-security config namespace, with `security:authentication-manager` element:

```
<beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class= "org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userManagerWs"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <security:authentication-manager id="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider ref="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
    </security:authentication-manager>
```

Comment: Is there any update if you have upgraded to spring-security version to 5.x version? Is this code will be compatible with this version?

Comment: @Nallamachu first snippet should be valid as list aware constructors still are available in `ProviderManager` in latest release 5.3.3. I am not sure of second solution, I guess it should work, but I have not used `spring-security` XML based initialization with Spring 5.x